# Registration App in Android Studio crashes without any view using SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, authentication, android-sqlite

I am working on Android Studio to create Login and Registration app using SQLite. I couldn't understand my error
the app gets closed automatically. Hoping someone could help me with the unknown error.

Activity 1 (MainActivity): If username and password details are correct. It navigates to HandsOnActivity(Activity 4).

Activity 2 (Registration Activity) : User details are entered like (Username, Password, Confirm Password, Email, Password) and Register button. To verify the user and add into Sqlite database.
**Username,Password,Confirm Password** gets input from **TextInputEditText** And **email,phonenumber** from **EditText.**
Activity3 and Activity 4 are been added with a simple textbox and layouts with setContentView().
I want to check both email and username while logining in into the app.

[Activity1 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlBBg.png)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.android.loginapp;
   import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText EditTextUserName;
        private EditText EditTextUserPassword;
        private Button buttonLogin;
        private Button buttonReset;
        private Button buttonCreateUser;
        LoginDatabase MyDb;
        String username = EditTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password = EditTextUserPassword.getText().toString();
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
    
            EditTextUserName = findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
            EditTextUserPassword =  findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
            buttonLogin = findViewById(R.id.button_login);
            buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
            buttonCreateUser = findViewById(R.id.button_createaccount);
            MyDb = new LoginDatabase(this);
            //Reset function
            buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditTextUserName.setText("");
                    EditTextUserPassword.setText("");
                }
            });
            //Create a new user function
            buttonCreateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(registerIntent);
                }
            });
            //Login button Navigation and Verification Function
            buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(username.isEmpty() | password.isEmpty()){
                        EditTextUserName.setError("Field can't be empty");
                        EditTextUserPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
                    } else{
                        boolean checkUsernamePassword = MyDb.checkUsernamePassword(username, password);
                        if(checkUsernamePassword){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UsernamePassword Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HandsOnActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                        } else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        boolean checkEmailPassword = MyDb.checkEmailPassword(username, password);
                        if(checkEmailPassword){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"EmailPassword Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HandsOnActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent2);
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    
        }
    }
```

RegistrationActivity. java file

```
package com.android.loginapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputLayout textInputUserName;
    TextInputLayout textInputUserPassword;
    TextInputLayout textInputUserConfirmPassword;
    EditText userPhoneNumber;
    EditText userEmailAddress;
    Button buttonRegisterUser;
    String MobilePattern="[0-9]{10}";
    LoginDatabase MyDb;
    String usernameInput = textInputUserName.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String passwordInput = textInputUserPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String confirmPasswordInput = textInputUserConfirmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    String phoneNumberInput = userPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    String emailInput = userEmailAddress.getText().toString().trim();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_activity);
        textInputUserName = findViewById(R.id.text_input_username);
        textInputUserPassword = findViewById(R.id.text_input_password);
        textInputUserConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.text_input_confirmPassword);
        userPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        userEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_emailAddress);
        buttonRegisterUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_registerUser);
        MyDb = new LoginDatabase(this);

        buttonRegisterUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!validateEmail() | !validateUsername() | !validatePassword() | !validatePhoneNumber()) {
                    return;
                }else if(passwordInput.equals(confirmPasswordInput)){
                    boolean checkUser = MyDb.checkUsername(usernameInput);
                    boolean checkEmail = MyDb.checkEmail(emailInput);
                    if(!checkUser & !checkEmail){
                        boolean insert = MyDb.insertData(usernameInput, passwordInput, phoneNumberInput, emailInput);
                        if (insert){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,RegisteredActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this,"User already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password doesn't match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean validateEmail () {
        if(emailInput.isEmpty()) {
            userEmailAddress.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailInput).matches()){
            userEmailAddress.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
            return  false;
        } else {
            userEmailAddress.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
     private boolean validateUsername() {
        if(usernameInput.isEmpty()) {
            textInputUserName.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else if(usernameInput.length()>15){
            textInputUserName.setError("Username too long");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputUserName.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
    private boolean validatePassword(){
        if(passwordInput.isEmpty() | confirmPasswordInput.isEmpty()){
            textInputUserPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
            textInputUserConfirmPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            textInputUserPassword.setError(null);
            textInputUserConfirmPassword.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
    private boolean validatePhoneNumber(){
        if(phoneNumberInput.isEmpty()){
            userPhoneNumber.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return false;
        } else if(phoneNumberInput.matches(MobilePattern)){
            return phoneNumberInput.length() > 6 && phoneNumberInput.length() <=10;
        }else{
            userPhoneNumber.setError("Number invalid");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Database File

```
package com.android.loginapp;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    
    
    public class LoginDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String DBNAME = "Login.db";
    
        public LoginDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users(username TEXT primary key, password TEXT, phoneNumber INTEGER, email VARCHAR(320))");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE if exists users");
        }
    
        public boolean insertData(String username, String password, String phoneNumber, String email){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("username", username);
            contentValues.put("password", password);
            contentValues.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            contentValues.put("email", email);
            long result = db.insert("users", null,contentValues);
            if(result == -1) return  false;
            else return true;
        }
        public boolean checkUsername(String username){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", new String[] {username});
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) return true; // If user exists
            else return false;
        }
    
        public boolean checkUsernamePassword(String username, String password){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users where username = ? and password = ?", new String[] {username,password});
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        public boolean checkEmail(String email){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",new String[] {email});
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        public boolean checkEmailPassword(String email, String password){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? and password = ?",new String[] {email, password});
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.loginapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisteredActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HandsOnActivity">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error found after debugging:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.android.loginapp/com.android.loginapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.android.loginapp | com.android.loginapp.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.android.loginapp | com.android.loginapp.test
Connected to process 1516 on device 'samsung-sm_m307f-RZ8M92DBXEE'.
Connecting to com.android.loginapp
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/ndroid.loginap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
E/ndroid.loginap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
    setConscryptValidator - put
W/ActivityThread: Application com.android.loginapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10111(com.android.loginapp) identical 3 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1499)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.loginapp, PID: 1516
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.loginapp/com.android.loginapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3341)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.loginapp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: After changing initialization of username and password in Activity1 to 
1. String username = EditTextUserName != null ? EditTextUserName.getText().toString() : null;
2. String password = EditTextUserPassword != null ? EditTextUserPassword.getText().toString() : null;  App shows only the 1st activity and closes when create user button is clicked.

Comment: .I have posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the following things wrong

```
String username = EditTextUserName.getText().toString();
String password = EditTextUserPassword.getText().toString();
```

The above two statements needs to be written after the following statements:

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(username.isEmpty() | password.isEmpty()){
                        EditTextUserName.setError("Field can't be empty");
                        EditTextUserPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
                    } else{
```

Just copy the first 2 statements below these. The reason you were getting NullPointer was that you were accessing variables that were not even initialized.

So your actual code would look like:-

```
buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(username.isEmpty() | password.isEmpty()){
                    EditTextUserName.setError("Field can't be empty");
                    EditTextUserPassword.setError("Field can't be empty");
                } else{
                    username = EditTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    password = EditTextUserPassword.getText().toString();
                    boolean checkUsernamePassword = MyDb.checkUsernamePassword(username, password);
                    if(checkUsernamePassword){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UsernamePassword 
                       Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                        HandsOnActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                      } else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid 
                        Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nadeem Shaikh! Thanks for you help. 
the code is running fine now.